# Hot to make part of background image transparent,not the whole

Tags: javascript

[image]

Look at this webpage, I used a background image, but now I want part of the picture to be transparent, such as,
X from 20-50,
Y from 30-70,

Any JavaScript libraries or native JavaScript can do this?

Comment: so currently your whole background image is transparent? I don't see that.

Comment: @KingKing current I don't set the opacity property for this image.

Comment: what if you set its opacity? I mean what is the behind scene you can see through the background? I guess it's just a solid white (or some other color) background.

Comment: @KingKing yes, you are right, I just want to see the solid white color~